# How to install "v4l1-compat.ko, videodev.ko, v4l2-common.ko" on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: linux, image-processing, camera, ubuntu-12.04, linux-device-driver

We are working on a robotic project and we will use a camera (ArtCam 130MI) for image processing on Ubuntu 12.04, the company have terminated Linux support but sent us the source codes for compiling the driver, but in load.sh file `v4l1-compat.ko, videodev.ko, v4l2-common.ko` files are needed in `/lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/media/video/`. So, we don't know how to install these files. Can you help us for this problem?

Comment: If you know more about that camera (esp. sensors) I think you may find already upstreamed drivers for some parts of it. Which interface it's using? What types of sensors? Why actually they didn't tell you anything about upstream? Did they fail to push their driver? What was the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to recompile your kernel with "Video4Linux" support enabled.
Enable config options VIDEO_V4L1 and VIDEO_V4L2 before compiling.

Comment: I don't know how to do this, can you help with it? How can I do this?